# Internal working of python Descriptor using Descriptor class

Tags: python-3.x

I am not able to understand how `age = AgeDescriptor()`  line is working .
At first glance It looks like we have three variables, name(instance variable),
age(instance variable), and age(class variable)) . class variable age is initialized to AgeDiscriptori i.e `age = AgeDescriptor()`. How this code is working internally and how `__set__` and `__get__` methods of discriptor is getting called when we are setting and getting the age. how this binding is performed internally.

```
class AgeDescriptor:

    def __init__(self):
        self._age = 0

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print('setter')
        self._age = value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print('getter')
        return self._age


class Person:
    age = AgeDescriptor()

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

    def set_age(self, value):
        self.age = value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    e1 = Person("ankit", 29)
```

Answer (score 0):

From "Programming in Python 3: A Complete Introduction" (chapter 8) by M. Summerfield:

> Descriptors are classes which provide access control for the attributes of other classes. Any class that implements one or more of the descriptor special methods, `__get__()`, `__set__()`, and `__delete__()`, is called (and can be used as) a descriptor.
>
> The built-in `property()` and `classmethod()` functions are implemented using descriptors. The key to understanding descriptors is that although we create an instance of a descriptor in a class as a class attribute, Python accesses the descriptor through the class’s instances.

So when you access `age` attribute like `e1.age` (or `self.age`) what happens is `Person.age.__get__(...)` because Python finds that the `Person` class has a descriptor with the name `age` and so uses the descriptor to get the attribute’s value. Similarly when you want to change `age` attribute like `e1.age = 100` (or `self.age = 100`) what happens is `Person.age.__set__(...)`.